# Using JAVAFX how would i make a label show numbers incrementing when i click a button

Tags: java, button, javafx, label

```
FeathersPerSec fps = new FeathersPerSec();
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    double getFeathers = fps.getNumOfFeathers();
    //double setFeathers = fps.setNumOfFeathers(1);
    double click = 1;


    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    Image image = new Image("dancingChicken.gif");
    Button chickenClick = new Button();

    Label  feathers  = new Label("FPS " + click);
    chickenClick.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

    chickenClick.setOnAction((e) -> {

         click++;
          feathers  = new Label("FPS" + click);
    });
```

heres a pieceof my program, im trying to make a cookie clicker type game. except with a chicken and feathers. Im trying to make it so when the user clicks the image button the number of feathers will increment by one. Im not sure what I should put in the setOnAction. with my current set up I keep getting a "Local Variable feathers defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the text of the current label, instead of creating a new label (which isn't part of your scene graph).

Additionally, you can't change a local variable inside a lambda expression (local variables accessed in a lambda expression must be final or *effectively final* (meaning they can only be assigned a value once)). The simplest fix for this is to move `click` to an instance variable:

```
private FeathersPerSec fps = new FeathersPerSec();
private double click ;

public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    double getFeathers = fps.getNumOfFeathers();
    //double setFeathers = fps.setNumOfFeathers(1);
    click = 1;


    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    Image image = new Image("dancingChicken.gif");
    Button chickenClick = new Button();

    Label  feathers  = new Label("FPS " + click);
    chickenClick.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

    chickenClick.setOnAction((e) -> {

         click++;
         feathers.setText("FPS" + click);
    });

}
```